# Connection refused when executing dump command in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a question. When I use dump command on windows shell like that :

```
neo4j-shell.bat -c 'dump MATCH(n:Airport) RETURN n;">bb.cypher
```

I got this :

```
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
     Connection refused
```

When I type -v, I got then a lot of information..

`C:\neo4j-community-3.1.1\bin>neo4j-shell -v COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Root is 'C:\neo4j-community-3.1.1' COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Server Type is 'Community' COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Version is '3.1.1' COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Database Mode is '' COMMENTAIRES : Shell command specified COMMENTAIRES : Java detected at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\java.exe' COMMENTAIRES : Executing C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\java.exe -version COMMENTAIRES : Java version response: java version "1.8.0_111" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-..`

and then list of jars
and then this:

`ERROR (-v for expanded information): Connection refused -host Domain name or IP of host to connect to (default: localhost) -port Port of host to connect to (default: 1337) -name RMI name, i.e. rmi://<host>:<port>/<name> (default: shell) -pid Process ID to connect to -c Command line to execute. After executing it the shell exits -file File containing commands to execute, or '-' to read from stdin. After executing it the shell exits -readonly Connect in readonly mode (only for connecting with -path) -path` ...

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to show extended information. Without it, nothing can be said.

Comment: I got this:
`C:\neo4j-community-3.1.1\bin>neo4j-shell -v
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Root is 'C:\neo4j-community-3.1.1'
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Server Type is 'Community'
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Version is '3.1.1'
COMMENTAIRES : Neo4j Database Mode is ''
COMMENTAIRES : Shell command specified
COMMENTAIRES : Java detected at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\java.exe'
COMMENTAIRES : Executing C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\java.exe -version
COMMENTAIRES : Java version response: java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-..` and then list of jars

Comment: and then this:
`ERROR (-v for expanded information):
        Connection refused

 -host      Domain name or IP of host to connect to (default: localhost)
 -port      Port of host to connect to (default: 1337)
 -name      RMI name, i.e. rmi://<host>:<port>/<name> (default: shell)
 -pid       Process ID to connect to
 -c         Command line to execute. After executing it the shell exits
 -file      File containing commands to execute, or '-' to read from stdin. After executing it the shell exits
 -readonly  Connect in readonly mode (only for connecting with -path)
 -path      ...`

Comment: It seems on my 3.1, I had to enable shell access for opening the shell port in the neo4j.conf file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034317/neo4j-shell-can-not-connect-to-neo4j-server

Comment: I'm really appreciated your help. It works perfectly but still got errors when I do dump command :
`.\neo4j-shell.bat -c 'dump MATCH(n:Airport) RETURN n;'>bb.cypher`
I think that the syntax is correct