# neo4j-shell can not connect to neo4j Server

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-shell

I'm using docker version of neo4j (v3.1.0) and I'm having difficulties connecting to neo4j server using neo4j-shell.

After running an instance of `neo4r:3.1.0` [docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j/), I run a bash inside the container:

```
$ docker exec -it neo4j /bin/bash
```

And from there I try to run the `neo4j-shell` like this:

```
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j-shell
```

But it errors:

```
$ /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j-shell 
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
    Connection refused

 -host      Domain name or IP of host to connect to (default: localhost)
 -port      Port of host to connect to (default: 1337)
 -name      RMI name, i.e. rmi://<host>:<port>/<name> (default: shell)
 -pid       Process ID to connect to
 -c         Command line to execute. After executing it the shell exits
 -file      File containing commands to execute, or '-' to read from stdin. After executing it the shell exits
 -readonly  Connect in readonly mode (only for connecting with -path)
 -path      Points to a neo4j db path so that a local server can be started there
 -config    Points to a config file when starting a local server

Example arguments for remote:
    -port 1337
    -host 192.168.1.234 -port 1337 -name shell
    -host localhost -readonly
    ...or no arguments for default values
Example arguments for local:
    -path /path/to/db
    -path /path/to/db -config /path/to/neo4j.config
    -path /path/to/db -readonly
```

I also tried other hosts like: `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `172.17.0.6` (the container IP). Since it didn't work I tried to list open ports on my container:

```
$ netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 :::7687                 :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::7473                 :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::7474                 :::*                    LISTEN      
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
```

As you can see there's no `1337` open! I've looked into the config file and the line for specifying port is commented out which means it should be set to its default value (1337).

Can anyone help me connect to neo4j using neo4j-shell?

BTW, the neo4j server is up and running and I can use its web access through port :7474.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 3.1 it seems the shell is not enabled by default.

You will need to pass your own configuration file with the shell enabled :

Uncomment

```
# Enable a remote shell server which Neo4j Shell clients can log in to.
dbms.shell.enabled=true
```

(I find the amount of worker for changing one value in docker quite heavy but yeah..)

Or use the new cypher-shell :

```
ikwattro@graphaware-team ~> docker ps -a | grep 'neo4j'
34b3c6718504        neo4j:3.1.0               "/docker-entrypoint.s"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                 7473-7474/tcp, 7687/tcp   compassionate_easley
2395bd0b1fe9        neo4j:3.1.0               "/docker-entrypoint.s"   5 minutes ago       Exited (143) 3 minutes ago                             cranky_goldstine
949feacbc0f9        neo4j:3.1.0               "/docker-entrypoint.s"   5 minutes ago       Exited (130) 5 minutes ago                             modest_boyd
c38572b078de        neo4j:3.0.6-enterprise    "/docker-entrypoint.s"   6 weeks ago         Exited (0) 6 weeks ago                                 fastfishpim_neo4j_1
ikwattro@graphaware-team ~> docker exec --interactive --tty compassionate_easley bin/cypher-shell
username: neo4j
password: *****
Connected to Neo4j 3.1.0 at bolt://localhost:7687 as user neo4j.
Type :help for a list of available commands or :exit to exit the shell.
Note that Cypher queries must end with a semicolon.
neo4j>
```

NB: Cypher-shell supports `begin` and `commit` :

```
neo4j> :begin
neo4j# create (n:Node);
Added 1 nodes, Added 1 labels
neo4j# :commit;
neo4j>
```

-

```
neo4j> :begin
neo4j# create (n:Person {name:"John"});
Added 1 nodes, Set 1 properties, Added 1 labels
neo4j# :rollback
neo4j> :commit
There is no open transaction to commit
neo4j>
```

http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/cypher-shell/

Comment: Thanks, but mostly I'm interested in `noe4j-shell` since it supports `BEGIN`, `COMMIT` and transactions. It seems cypher-shell does not. Could you please tell me which entry in configuration controls neo4j-shell?

Comment: Fair enough, I amended my answer with the line

Comment: Note that cypher-shell supports begin and commit, added an example